# Nodejs Firebase reference to database keeps on checking value

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried creating one program which fetch data from firebase database from node js server.

```
function FCM()
{
    var payload = {
      data: {
           //Some data
      }
    };

    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("PATH_TO_DATABASE");

    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      registrationToken = REGISTRATION TOKEN

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });


    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}
```

But when this function gets completed then the server keeps on running as usual which is fine but the problem is that when any data gets deleted from PATH_TO_DATABASE then it gives error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Now I don't want firebase to keep on checking the value to that path. I just want to free that thing. So how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref.on("value")` is going to trigger whenever that value changes, like when the data is deleted. Instead use

`ref.once("value", function(snapshot)`

Then `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)` won't get triggered again.